# QGIS getting Bad Request reply from ArcMap feature service

Tags: arcgis-server, feature-service, qgis-3

I have the QGIS 3.2 version and I cannot get any services connected.

Is the ArcMap feature service not available in this version?

I always get this message:

> Failed to download capabilities:
>
> Download of capabilities failed: Error transferring
> http://ecn.t3.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a%7Bq%7D.jpeg?g=1%0A&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
>
> - server replied: Bad Request

Comment: What does the URL with WMS service structure to do with ArcMap feature service?

Comment: That's an invalid URL. The Bing maps tiles are not a WMS, nor are they an ArcGIS Feature Service

Answer (score 2):

For **Bing Virtual Earth** Tiles.

Use XYZ Connection in QGIS 3.20

```
http://ecn.t3.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a{q}.jpeg?g=1
```

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: i keep getting this message:

Comment: Cannot open A.shp.(Unable to open A.shx or A.SHX. Set SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX config option to YES to restore or create it.)

Comment: @AvigailNewman-Cohen not sure that error is related to  this question of consuming VE tiles, you might have another issue with your install (or plugin). (shx is the index file for a shapefile)